# How to constrain select's defaultValue to one of the option's values in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, html-select

How could I type `Select`'s props so that the `defaultValue` is constrained to one of the `options` values (`"au" | "nz"` in this example)?

```
const countryOptions = [
  {
    value: "au",
    label: "Australia",
  },
  {
    value: "nz",
    label: "New Zealand",
  }
] as const;

// This should produce an error because "foo" is neither "au" or "nz"
<Select options={countryOptions} defaultValue="foo" ... />
```

Comment: Can you do it like `<Select options={countryOptions} defaultValue={countryOptions[0].value} ... />` if you know your `countryOptions` will always contain more than one values.

Comment: Which library are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use generics to capture the type of the `options` props and you can use indexed access types to get the actual type of `value`

```
function Select<T extends { readonly value: string, readonly label: string }>(p: { options: readonly T[], defaultValue: T['value'] }) {
    return <div />
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChS0IA7AZ3koFcqYoBPAeTBmGprgF44AbVJw4Ab1Fi4ANxQAbBkgBccAEQoGagDRSx8lACMk81WoCCDOlAXAUOqQF9dYydNkKlZqgC8H7g2NTdQA5JAB3OAAtVAMqABN-OEdSAF04FD5KWhgAbnJMJgweKjgAZRMkDAAeABU4JAAPGCQEvnE4IhR46nlWD0UVOGtgKgBzbU7UHqo+uECTVRHx5IA+AAowVQ6ILhKaVS6ZudqhVMn4pExNeRgANU8h0-w5Qfx0xwBKCT0pmAYoKVqvFgDI4AB6VakFKkQpUYrUOC1JB0ABM62+bmk4PBSIAFsA+DQ8RAGPJ4nAwDh4gw0EgMqUkFAcFA4MY0JoaPS1JgIBA1HBCXAqEhgDA8Uz1JoBdB1L41L8iP9AXBqhV5FV4LtuLx+OJGMw2JwdbRHHBLtcyfdHvwNFoxJDoQUiiakSiYBifu4cfihcTSeTKdTafSUIzmbL2Zzubz+YK+CKxRLWXaZSn5YqkMqgerNXBtfs9QaWBw9rwzRabtbBrbYwKIVDHEA)

You could also use a generic just for the `value` field. (You will need to use `& {}` on `defaultValue` to decrease the priority of that inference site.

```
function Select<T extends string>(p: { options: ReadonlyArray<{ value: T, label: string }>, defaultValue: T & {} }) {
    return <div />
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChS0IA7AZ3koFcqYoBPAeTBmGprgF44AbVJw4Ab1Fi4ANxQAbBkgBccAEQoGagDRSx8lACMk81WoCCDOlAXAUOqQF9dYydNkKlZqgC8H7g2NTdQA5JAB3OAAtVAMqABN-OEdSAF04FD5KWhgAbnJMJgweKjgAZRMkDAAeABU4JAAPGCQEvmtgKgBzAD4ACjBVcTgILhKaVWQUeOp5VnMoG1Zq4blFFTha7ThAk1UO7uSe7fikTE15GAA1Tw36gDIJR2SASgk9OCIYBihS6vjgDI4AB6HqkFKkQpUYrUTZIOgAJj6bzc0mBwM2AAtgO1MRAGPJ4nAwDh4gw0EgMqUkItoHBjGhNDRKWpMBAIGo4Di4FQkMAYJiaepNJy6WpfGoPl8fn8KvIqvBRtxePxxIxmGxOMraM9TucCddbvwNFoxKDwQUitq4XRke93OisdyaHiCUSSRAyRSqQ1aVB6VUmSy2RyuXxefzBf6TaLoxKpUhvr84NU5QqRmMVWr8RqOJmdXA9RdDetjSHOSCwY4gA)

Comment: Thanks!! Where could I learn more about the `& {}` bit?

Comment: @MishaMoroshko ‍♂️ I found it on github issues a while ago.. Not really sure it's documented explicitly elsewhere